# Help with understanding a proof involving subsequences, $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Source: Elementary Analysis By Kenneth A. Ross

I am having trouble understanding the last part of the proof of theorem 11.7.

> "Theorem 11.2(i) shows that a **monotonic** subsequence of $s_n$ converges to $t = \lim \sup s_n$"

However, Theorem 11.2(i) does not require the subsequence of $s_n$ converging to $t$ to be **monotonous**, which is something that theorem 11.7 requires.

> Theorem 11.7: 
> Let ($s_n$) be any sequence. There exists a **monotonic** subsequence whose limit is $\limsup s_n$ and there exists a monotonic subsequence whose limit is $\lim \inf s_n$.

> Proof: 
> If ($s_n$) is not bounded above, then by Theorem 11.2(ii), a monotonic subsequence of ($s_n$) has limit $+\infty = \limsup s_n$. Similarly, if ($s_n$) is not bounded below, a monotonic subsequence has limit $-\infty = \liminf s_n$.

> The remaining cases are that ($s_n$) is bounded above or is bounded below. These cases are similar, so we only consider the case that ($s_n$) is bounded above, so that lim sup $s_n$ is finite. Let $t = \limsup s_n$, and consider $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $N_0$ so that

> $\sup\{s_n : n > N\} < t + \epsilon$ for $ N \geq N_0$.
> In particular, $s_n$ $ < t + \epsilon $ for all $n > N_0$. We now claim
> $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : t - \epsilon $ < $s_n$ < $t + \epsilon\}$ is infinite.

> Otherwise, there exists $N_1 > N_0$ so that $s_n$ $\leq t - \epsilon$ for $n > N_1$. Then $\sup \{s_n : n > N\} \leq t - \epsilon$ for $N \geq N_1$, so that $\limsup s_n < t$, a contradiction. Since (1) holds for each $\epsilon > 0$, Theorem 11.2(i) shows that a monotonic subsequence of $(s_n)$ converges to $t = \limsup s_n$.

---

> Theorem 11.2(i):
> If $t$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converging to $t$ if and only if the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : |s_n - t| < \epsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon > 0$.

---

> Theorem 11.2 (ii):
> If the sequence $(s_n)$ is unbounded above, it has a subsequence with limit $+\infty$.

Comment: It's likely they meant, by checking the *proof* of $11.2$ you can see $(s_n)$ is (can be chosen to be) monotonous